# Why doesn't the Input tag parsed from php work by jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I wonder why jQuery events don't work at the HTML tag parsed from PHP code.

I have a PHP code and, the main web page has same jQuery code as the script in the PHP code.

PHP code is below.

```
echo "<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(\"input\").focus(function(){
        $(this).css(\"background-color\", \"#000000\");
    });
    $(\"input\").blur(function(){
        $(this).css(\"background-color\", \"#ffffff\");
    });
});
</script>";
    echo  " 기사평 : <img src='./imoticon/good.png' style='width:23px;height:23px;' title='좋아요'>좋아요<img src='./imoticon/bad.png' style='width:23px;height:23px;' title='싫어요'>싫어요";
    echo " <option  id=".$i." onclick=\"showComment".$i."(this.value)\" value=".$item_link4."> Show Comments </option>
          <div id='showComment".$i."'></div>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='inputComment' size='150' id='input".$i."' onfocus=\"this.value=''\" value=\"댓글\" ><button onclick=\"inputComment".$i."(document.getElementById('input".$i."').value)\" >완료</button><button onclick=\"document.getElementById('input".$i."').value = ''\">댓글 재세팅</button>
              <input type='text' name='txtfile' id='txt".$i."' value=".$item_link4." hidden>
              <div id='comment".$i."'><b>입력하신 댓글이 아직 없습니다.</b></div>";

 }
```

But, jQuery event doesn't happen.
why?
Of course, I have 2 thousand lines of javascript code in the main web page. The Id of input tag will be sending the input text to another javascript code.

FYI
I am making RSS's comment board as below.
[image]

Comment: An `id` shouldn't be an integer. Do you really have multiple `showComment` and `inputComment` functions?.. or maybe I'm misreading that

Comment: Id is composed of the integer and string. Yeah, inputComment() javascript function is going. 1 element tag has to belong to 1 javascript or 1 jQuery?

Comment: Did you see  how the  code was actually rendered in the browser (through "View Source" or similar)? If so, could you share that? When you mix PHP and Javascript, I think it might be easy to introduce a syntax or other error that may not be immediately evident in the PHP script.

Comment: @KellyMarchewa PHP source code is not rendered 'cause of RSS. I am making the comment & recomment for every RSS article automatically.